# Acessar site no celular sem estar conectado a rede

Tags: android, html5, css3

Fiz um site em `HTML5` e coloquei na IDE chamada `NetBeans` executei o projeto e ele veio com a seguinte url: `http://localhost:8383/tecmov/index.html`.

Através dela eu posso acessar meu projeto de outra máquina desde que ela esteja na mesma rede, porém estou na empresa e meu projeto está sendo executado no computador da empresa, em uma rede diferente do meu celular.

Queria acessar esse meu site do meu celular Android sem me conectar à rede da empresa. Isso é possível? Via cabo `USB`, por exemplo, pois não sei uma forma de fazer isso...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos por partes.

Sim, é possível acessar este site Offline, desde que você copie todo o projeto para dentro do seu cartão SD do celular e este seja desenvolvido em HTML, pois o celular possui o interpretador HTML, ou seja, você acessara o site sem acesso a internet, porém toda vez que atualizar algo no site no seu computador terá de copiar os novos arquivos e paginas para o SD.

Para acessar ele sem fazer o que falei acima, você precisara pedir ao Administrador da rede de seu trabalho que ingresse seu Smartphone ao domínio, para isso ele ingressara o IP ou Endereço MAC do seu aparelho na rede ou lhe dará acesso a rede WiFi da empresa (caso possua).

Eu utilizo este mesmo esquema, para ver como meu site ficaria em um celular, ele esta no meu Micro e acesso ele via WiFi no meu celular, para isso Eu logo an rede WiFi com o mesmo usuário e  senha que uso para ligar meu micro, é um WiFi privado.

Comment: devo salvar em alguma parte especifica do celular ?

Comment: @Kirito não, mas fica mais organizado se você criar uma pasta no cartão SD, salvar la e depois criar um atalho na tela principal para a pagina index.html ficara mais facil acessar.